# How to correctly call the superclass' constructor in the subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I completely understand how inheritance and the super keyword works, but not of this kind.

```
public class Stack<T> implements StackADT<T> {
    /**
     * The array into which the objects of the stack are stored.
     */
    private T[] data;
    /**
     * The number of objects in this stack.
     */
    private int size;
    /**
     * The default capacity of this stack.
     */
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    /**
     * Constructs a new Stack with capacity for 100 objects
     */
    public Stack(){
        this.data = (T[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public Stack(int size){
        this.data = (T[]) new Object[size];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }
```

How would I call this constructor in a subclass of Stack?
I need to change the capacity to 52 in the subclass called discardPile.

Examples I've done before were like this

```
private double salary = 1500;

public Faculty(String n, String i, String o, double s) {
    super(n, i, o); //where names = n, i = ID, and o = office were inheriented from their parents' constructors which assigned name = n; and etc. 

    salary = s; //unique instance variable
}
```

Which is a much more simple example since there aren't multiple constructors to work with and things are assigned to letters.

I just want to understand how to call a method in these cases.

Comment: not sure what you ask for, but maybe you just try to call super(52);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
public class discardPile<T> extends Stack<T> {
  discardPile() {
    super(52);
  }
}
```

The constructor called will be chosen based on the argument(s) you provide.

Comment: Right now, Eclipse is telling me to remove the argument to match Stack<T>. I need to call the size in the constructor, as well.

Comment: @LostSoul: It compiles for me.  What do you want to *do* with the size?

Comment: @David Herring I think I figured it out. I based it on what you gave me, so I'll accept it as the answer :) I just needed that as the capacity for the stack.